# Nested ANOVA and Assigning Proportion of Variation

Tags: anova, nested-data

I have blood biomarker data from 6 subjects. Blood was collected on 3 occasions from each individual. Each blood sample was processed 3 times (3 technical replicates).

I want to use these data to ascribe proportion of variation among the factors subject, sampling time, and technical replicate.

I've been advised Nested ANOVA can do this. However it's not clear to me what calculations provided by resulting Nested Anova table are used to assign the proportion of variation attributable to the 3 factors of interest.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have data from 6 persons, each having a blood sample taken thrice, and each blood sample analysed thrice. To ascibe variance components at each level, that can be done from an anova table, but the modern, direct way is to fit a random effects model with nested random effects. For your data we can write a model as
$$
  Y_{ijk}=\mu + r_i + r_{ij} + r_{ijk}
$$ where $i$ is person, $j$ is occasion within person and $k$ is technical replicate within occasion and person. We can show an analysis in R with some simulated data:

```
set.seed(7*11*13)
testdata <- rnested(n=c(6, 3, 3), sigma=c(5, 2, 1), mu=10)
testdf <- data.frame(testdata,
                     person=factor(rep(1:6, each=9)),
                     occasion=factor(rep(1:(6*3), each=3)))
mod.nested <- lme4::lmer(testdata  ~ (1 | person/occasion),  data=testdf)
summary(mod.nested)
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: testdata ~ (1 | person/occasion)
   Data: testdf

REML criterion at convergence: 239.1

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.22883 -0.55431 -0.00988  0.52664  2.06449 

Random effects:
 Groups          Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 occasion:person (Intercept)  5.374   2.318   
 person          (Intercept) 48.455   6.961   
 Residual                     1.718   1.311   
Number of obs: 54, groups:  occasion:person, 18; person, 6

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)    9.280      2.899   3.201
```

Turns out there is also a dedicated R package for variance component models, `VCA`, containing some useful function. It can give this plot

[image: varPlot of data, showing the nesting structure]

nicely showing the nesting structure of the data.

Was produced by `VCA::varPlot(testdata  ~ person/occasion, Data=testdf)`.  We can also use this package to get a more traditional variance component analysis table:

```
 VCA::fitVCA(testdata  ~ person/occasion, testdf)  


Result Variance Component Analysis:
-----------------------------------

  Name            DF       SS          MS         VC        %Total    SD      
1 total           6.048519                        55.548053 100       7.453057
2 person          5        2269.697527 453.939505 48.455353 87.231415 6.960988
3 person:occasion 12       214.095976  17.841331  5.374315  9.675074  2.318257
4 error           36       61.861858   1.718385   1.718385  3.093511  1.310872
  CV[%]    
1 80.312995
2 75.010538
3 24.981182
4 14.125754

Mean: 9.280013 (N = 54) 

Experimental Design: balanced  |  Method: ANOVA
```

Note that the variance component estimates from this analysis is identical with the above from `lmer`.

The function used for simulating the nested data is:

```
rnested <- function(n=c(6, 3, 3), # n's for each level ...
                    sigma=c(5, 1, 1),  # standard dev for each level
                    mu=10,  # 
                    rfun = rnorm) {
    r <- length(n)
    stopifnot(length(sigma)==r)
    N <- cumprod(n)
    res <- rep(mu, length=N[r])
    for (i in seq_along(n)) res <- res + rep(rfun(N[i], mean=0, sd=sigma[i]),
                                             each=N[r]/N[i])
    return(res)
}
```

Comment: This is extremely helpful, thank you for taking time to respond! While awaiting a response I started reading about REML since it appears to be one of the preferred ways JMP software goes about assigning variability. I wonder if you have an opinion of how one might cite REML methodology for a peer reviewed paper? It seems as though "RR Corbeil and SR Searle (1976) Restricted Maximum Likelihood (REML) Estimation of Variance Components in the Mixed Model, Technometrics, 18:31-38" may be appropriate?

Comment: Could be as well as any, my preferred reference is https://www.amazon.com/Mixed-Effects-Models-S-PLUS-Statistics-Computing/dp/1441903178

Comment: Note that one nice property of the REML estimates is that it leads to the same variance component estimates as the traditional anova method, at least in balanced designs. But it is more general, and with modern software, more easy to use.

Comment: In fact I do not have a perfectly balanced design for another data set that I'd like to work up, so this additional advice about REML characteristics is important. Thanks again, super helpful.

Comment: One follow-up question. There is a right skew to the data so I ordinarily log10 transform these biomarker response data before performing parametric tests such as ANOVA. Is that generally the case for REML estimates as well, that the response data should be approximately normally distributed, so transformation is advisable as necessary?

Comment: You can stil use log-transform (and othet transforms), but there are other possibilities today. With non-normal responses there is glm's (generalized linear models), and their extensions to mixed models, glmm's. For specifics with your case, you could ask a new question, with much more detail. Link back here!